# How to connect to Oracle on SSMA tool?

Tags: oracle, azure

Hope you can help. I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using SSMA for Oracle.

I have created an Oracle VM on azure as highlighted below

[image]

and

[image]

the VM got created

[image]

I have added the firewall rule to allow 1521 port.

[image]

and created the DB as mentioned below

[image]

however I could not connect to the Oracle instance using SSMA

it is throwing the below error

[image]

and if I try with that account

[image]

it is not accepting the password

[image]

What is the Username and password to be used?

Reference: https://lovekesh.tech/how-to-install-oracle-database-in-microsoft-azure-vm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the "system" account instead of "sys" or "sysdba", passsword for "system" account  is same as "sys" account.

[image]

and could convert the schema

[image]

and I see the progress as highlighted below

[image]

as well as I could migrate the data

[image]

and status is as shown below

[image]